# Can a row with a bigger auto-increment value appear sooner than a row with a smaller one?

Tags: mysql, innodb, auto-increment

Is the following scenario possible?

MySQL version 5.6.15

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
    id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT.
    data1 int,
    data2 timestamp,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

innodb_autoinc_lock_mode = 1

---

AUTO_INCREMENT=101

- 0 ms: Query A is run: `INSERT INTO my_table (data1, data2) VALUES (101, FROM_TIMESTAMP(1418501101)), (102, FROM_TIMESTAMP(1418501102)),` .. [200 values in total] .., `(300, FROM_TIMESTAMP(1418501300));`
- 500 ms: Query B is run: `INSERT INTO my_table (data1, data2) VALUES (301, FROM_TIMESTAMP(1418501301));`
- 505 ms: Query B is completed. The row gets id=301.
- 1000 ms: `SELECT id FROM my_table WHERE id >= 300;` — would return one row (id=301).
- 1200 ms: Query A is completed. The rows get id=101 to id=300.
- 1500 ms: `SELECT id FROM my_table WHERE id >= 300;` — would return two rows (id=300, id=301).

In other words, is it possible that the row with id=301 can be selected earlier than it's possible to select the row with id=300?

And how to avoid it, if it is possible?

Comment: Did you try it? Could you insert ID 301 before 300?

Comment: I'm debugging a problem and this is what seems to have happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why is query A taking more than a second to run? Yuck! And yes what you're seeing is exactly how I'd expect it to behave.

Primary keys 101 through 300 are reserved immediately while inserting the new rows. This takes a couple of milliseconds. It then spends more than 1 second rebuilding the indexes and half way through doing all of that you ran another query which inserted a new row, using the next available auto_increment: 301.

As Alin Purcaru said you can avoid this specific issue by changing the lock mode, but it will cause performance issues (Instead of executing in 5 milliseconds, query B will take 700 milliseconds to execute.

Under high load situations the problem gets exponentially worse and you'll eventually see "too many connection" errors, effectively bringing your whole database offline.

Also there are other rare situations where auto_increment can give "out of order" increments, which will not be solved by locking.

Personally I think the best option is to use UUIDs instead of auto_increment for the primary key, and then have a timestamp column (as a double with microseconds) to determine what order rows were inserted into the database.

Comment: Those are approximate times to deliver the idea, but not too far off — the DB is loaded with a lot of other stuff, not just these two queries. And such longer-than-usual queries happen from time to time and is the cause for problems that appear rarely (and thus is harder to debug). :) The thing is that in my case (using the logs I have) I am not completely certain that this what happened (I do not have the precise ms times or order for all the actions), but it seemed likely, that's why I asked.

Comment: So, if I use a timestamp column with microseconds (`DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`) and then order by it, the row with id=301 would be the first one, and the rows with id=101 to id=300 would have a bigger timestamp and thus come afterwards? Then I can use that column value to separate the unprocessed rows from the processed ones.

Comment: Personally I wouldn't use `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. I'd just make it a `double` and use `microtime(true)` in PHP (or the equivalent in whatever other language). I find there are less bugs when I write the code myself instead of relying on MySQL's internal (and often overly complicated) behaviour. Also I think MySQL timestamp columns only store seconds, so all 200 rows being inserted will have exactly the same value, and you won't know what order they were inserted in. `mycrotime(true)` in PHP gives you microseconds.

Comment: I want to rely on MySQL to register the insertion order because there are several independent programs on different servers that do the inserts. I did an actual test which confirmed that the described situation really can happen. Unfortunately, a CURRENT_TIMESTAMP column is not any different than the AUTO_INCREMENT one, in this regard: the older row that get to be selected sooner than the newer ones not only has the bigger id, but also the bigger inserted time value.

Comment: If you want the timestamp to be the end of the insert instead of the beginning of the insert, just do `update my_table set created_date = current_timestamp where uuid = '...'`

Answer (score 1):

So... I read [the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-auto-increment-configurable.html) for you.

According to them when what you have in your example is two *simple inserts* (the multi-insert is still considered simple, even if it has multiple rows, because you know how many you will insert, so the end autoincrement value may be determined), and when you have `innodb_autoinc_lock_mode = 1` no lock will be set on the table and you can have your second query finish before the first and have that row available before.

If you want to avoid this, you need to set `innodb_autoinc_lock_mode = 0`, but you may take a toll in terms of scalability.

*Disclaimer: I haven't tried it and the answer is based on my understanding of the MySQL docs.*

Comment: Such were my suspicions too, after reading the docs, but I wanted a confirmation from someone who knows MySQL better. :)